# Dependencies with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, yarnpkg

So I'm using webpack encore within a symfony project, and I have this github repo with a jQuery plugin, and I would like to import this plugin to use it in my code, but I don't get how to do that; even though I'm sure it's a very classic use case...
This dependency should be resolved with yarn or webpack, or both ?
I googled of course but I didn't find anything expliciting it.
I don't really master webpack, so I'm really looking for a "step by step"-like explaination.
I own the repository that has the plugin, it has a bower.json file, but no other package manager file (so no package.json file for instance) but I totally can add some support if needed (I guess it will be needed).

The plugin code is something like that :

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    pluginFunction: function(options) {
        return $(this).each(function() {
            // code
        });
    }
});
```

So to rephrase : I own a repository with a jQuery module. With the javascript code of my other project, I want to be able to use it (for instance `$('#selector').pluginFunction();` ).
Thank you

Comment: Hello @HelloSir, please provide some more Information. E.g. a link to the GitHub Repo with the jQuery plugin you want to import into you project. Also some information like a code example about how you have tried to import the plugin. By the way, webpack and yarn are completely different things. Webpack is a module bundler whereas yarn is a package manager. Another popular package manager is npm. So please give us some more information about your Issue and take care to express facts precisely and not to confuse them. The better we can help you :)

Comment: I detailed a bit. I'd rather not share the repository link, but I explained its state. So if I'm correct it's not a webpack problem, but only a package manager problem, so in my case yarn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would recommend discarding the bower.json file. [Bower died a long time ago](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/).

Add a package.json file, with a `main` property pointing to your plugin file.

```
{
    "name": "my-plugin",
    "main": "my-plugin.js",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.5.0"
    }
}
```

Now within your plugin JavaScript, you'll want to wrap the code within a UMD (Universal Module Definition). This allows your plugin to be loaded through AMD, CommonJS *and* as a browser global.

```
(function (factory) {
    // Universal Module Definition
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["jquery"], factory);
    } else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(jQuery);
    }
})(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {
        // plugin code here
    };
});
```

Webpack supports both AMD and CommonJS definitions, so it'll use the first one it comes across - AMD in this case.

At this point I would recommend publishing the package to NPM to make it easier to use in your project, but you can also add GitHub repositories as pacakges with yarn:

```
yarn add https://github.com/HelloSir/my-plugin
```

Now you can simply `require` your plugin in your app code to attach it to jQuery:

```
const $ = require('jquery');
require('my-plugin');

$('.selector').myPlugin();
```